# Negligible dam capacity to exclude from a runoff module

Tags: hydrology, models

I am running the WRSM-Pitman model for the upper reaches of a quaternary catchment (which is smaller than its intended use for full quaternary catchments or larger areas). The total catchment area is 49.2 km2 and the distributed farm dams cover a total area of 0.0754 km2. Are there any guidelines for dam capacities or areas below which their influence is negligible in the model and the dam can be excluded from the runoff module area (i.e. catchment area)?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the area for dams, lakes and wetlands can be excluded from your runoff modules, especially if they exceed about 10% of the catchment.
Less than that the effect will be small and the respective components can be included or excluded in the catchment area.